# What is negation (not) of a bit vector in VHDL

Tags: vector, vhdl, bit

What does it mean to do a negation of a bit vector in VHDL? For example if I have 10100111 which is a bit vector called temp and I do something like temp := not temp what will my output be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "not" on vectors. Just run the program below with ModelSim or ISim and the inverted/negated bit vector will be printed in the console.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.numeric_bit.ALL;

entity test is
end entity test;

architecture beh of test is

    function vec_image(arg : bit_vector) return string is
        -- original author Mike Treseler (http://mysite.ncnetwork.net/reszotzl/)
        -- recursive function call turns ('1','0','1') into "101"
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        constant arg_norm        : bit_vector(1 to arg'length) := arg;
        constant center          : natural := 2;     --  123
        variable bit_image       : string(1 to 3);   --  '0'
        variable just_the_number : character;
    begin
        if (arg'length > 0) then
            bit_image       := bit'image(arg_norm(1));   -- 3 chars: '0'
            just_the_number := bit_image(center);              -- 1 char    0
            return just_the_number                          -- first digit
            & vec_image(arg_norm(2 to arg_norm'length)); -- rest the same way
            else
            return ""; -- until "the rest" is nothing
        end if;
    end function vec_image;
begin

    demo:process is
        variable bitvec : bit_vector (7 downto 0) := "10100111";
    begin
        report vec_image(bitvec);
        report vec_image(not bitvec); -- not bit vector
        wait;
    end process demo;

end architecture beh;
```

Answer (score 11):

A bit-wise inversion.

In general in VHDL (LRM 7.2.1): "For the unary operation `not` defined on one-dimensional array types, the operation is performed on each element of the operand, and the result is an array with the same index range as the operand."

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to *negate* a vector, you need to use a vector which has certain properties defined for it.  Specifically:

- some notion of numerical value (so you can't use `bit_vector` or `std_logic_vector`, which are just collections of bits)
- some notion of "sign"

From the `ieee.numeric_std` package, you should use the `signed` type for this:

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
variable a,b:signed(8 downto 0);
...
a := "000000001";
b := -a;
```